# How can I download and use the installer package for Ubuntu Server in an already installed ubuntu server system?

Tags: server, system-installation, usb-installation

The ubuntu server iso has an installer where you can set various variables, partition your drives etc.

How can I access this installer from an installed ubuntu server system to make modifications?
Can I install a package, if so, what is the package called?

Comment: Are you trying to run the graphical installer remotely?

Comment: You've got a point there as I read about the cli installer being able to be accessed via ssh.
For the server the cli installer seems to be default.
Still the question remains if I can use the installer after the system was installed to make modifications. I will update my question and remove the vnc tag and alternative.

Comment: It should be possible to install and use the tools used by the installer for those tasks separately or other tools for the same purpose, for exampole [tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) or `fdisk` or `gdisk`. You can ask specifically for the tasks you want to perform and get answers (in separate questions).

Comment: You can't repartition partitions with live filesystems anyway.  At best you can only repartition unused space unless you boot from a live disk and resize existing partitions, and even that is dangerous and not always possible.